# Custom Save method to update last_modified date

Tags: python, django

Given the following model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    imdb_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

How would I implement a custom save method to update these two fields? Something like:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()

        # update the created date
        if not self.pk:
            self.created = now

        # update the last modified
        previous_obj = Title.objects.get(pk=self.pk) # a way to do this without a second query?
        if (previous_obj.name != self.name) or (previous_obj.imdb_id != self.imdb_id):
            self.last_updated = now

        super(Title, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you really need to find out if the model has really been modified ? Can't you just assume that if `save()` is called then it's been modified ?

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use the `auto_now=True` kwarg? Writing a custom save method for this sounds ultra-WET when you've got built-in functionality for this already. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now).

Comment: I'm trying to see if the fields change. I update this on an xml feed which runs every night. If the fields are always the same, doing an `auto_now_add=True` would return a false positive.